# custom handler not working when using webpack

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have a custom handler that I use in getting radiobutton checked value:

```
export const radioChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
        viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        var newValueAccessor = function () {
            return {
                change: function () {
                    value(element.value);
                }
            }
        };
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor,
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
        viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if ($(element).val() == ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(element).closest('.btn').button('toggle');
            }, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm importing and registering it in my viewmodel:

```
let ko = require('knockout');
let radioChecked = require('../general/handler/radioChecked');

(function () {
    ko.bindingHandlers.radioChecked = radioChecked;

    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.currentView = ko.observable();
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})();
```

the binder only work on initial load, however, when the radio button is click, that binder update is not triggered.

this was working file before moving to webpack + babel-loader.

Do anyone know how to make KO custom binders work when loading modules with Webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one file called knockout-bindings.js. All of my custom bindings are in that folder

```
// -- Contents of knockout-bindings.js -- //
var ko = require('knockout');

ko.bindingHandlers.datePicker = {...}
ko.bindingHandlers.editableText = {...}
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {...}
```

Then in the webpack source app.js I just do a straight up require at the top of the file. No need to setup the objects there.

```
const ko = require('knockout');
require('./assets/js/knockout-bindings.js')

(function () {
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.currentView = ko.observable();
    }

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})();
```

Your includes should use **const** instead of **let**, there shouldn't be a reason they would mutate.